# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setDailyData is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an error in below code and I don't know what should I do.

```
const { dailyData, setDailyData } = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAPI = async () => {
    setDailyData(await fetchDailyData());
};

    fetchAPI();
  });
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHCzX.jpg)

Comment: Please include more code as it seems you have not defined `setDailyData`.

Comment: That's not how `useState` works. It returns an array - you destructure by _index_, not by name. Think about it - how could it possibly know you intend to call the value `dailyData` and the setter `setDailyData`, based on the only information you've passed to it (an empty array)?

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is that you are extracting the properties from `useState` incorrectly.

---

The `useState` function returns an `array`, from which you destructure the properties by index.

To destructure the returned value of `useState`, you need to use square brackets (`[]`) instead of curly braces (`{}`).

So, the fixed code would look like so.

```js
const [dailyData, setDailyData] = useState([]);
```

This will assign the values of the array to the variables as so.

| Index | Variable |
| --- | --- |
| `0` | `dailyData` |
| `1` | `setDailyData` |

---

In conclusion, you have to destructure the `useState` return value by index (e.g. `0`, `1`, etc.), instead of by name.